# In sonarqube Web page is not displaying

Tags: sonarqube

I am working in SonarQube the process is fully running in command prompt but the web page is not displaying. I changed the address and port in the sonar properties but still the web page is not displaying.

If I load webpage it is showing as connection refused.

```
D:\>cd D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\bin\windows-x86-64

    D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
    wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
    wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
    jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
    jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
    jvm 1    |
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:49:09 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\temp
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:49:09 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:49:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\temp\conf\es
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:49:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:49:13 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:49:13 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:49:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:49:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\temp\sq-process1476121489817180909properties
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:51:08 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is up
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:51:08 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='ce', ipcIndex=3, logFilenamePrefix=ce]] from [D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;./lib/ce/*;D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\temp\sq-process446994653925487374properties
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:51:13 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is up
    jvm 1    | 2018.01.05 17:51:13 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is up
```

Comment: Check the logs: _$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs_. You'll likely find something helpful there.

Comment: more helpful will be if you will put sonar config file, instead of the log, this log from command line is saying sonar started successfully ... 
Also you can recheck open ports in machine with `nestat` command on Win

Comment: from your drive / directory naming it looks like a corporate computer, any firewall ?

Comment: @gjambet Yes it is corporate machine. But my collegue able to start the server without any issue. How can I check is there any firewall blocking for my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long search, below solution worked for me.

I have tried disabling proxy and hit the sonar server URL (http://127.0.0.50:9111/). It worked. Since I need proxy setup, i have added my ip and port in the exceptions of proxy.

Thanks everyone who extended help here. :)

**Config file entry is**

`sonar.web.host=127.0.0.50
sonar.web.port=9111`